# Pairing/Grouping Object data

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a JSON object with data that I'm trying to display on my site but when I iterate the object, the labels and values are listed separately; whereas I'd want to group them to correlate data to each label.

Here is my data that I've retrieved from the JSON object:

```
[value, 155]
[end_time, 2014-10-31T07:00:00+0000]
[value, 785]
[end_time, 2014-11-01T07:00:00+0000]
[value, 183]
[end_time, 2014-11-02T07:00:00+0000]
```

and I want the result to be something like:

```
2014-10-31: 155
2014-11-01: 785
2014-11-02: 183
```

Is there a pairing or other method I can use to achieve this?

*edit* JSON is only incidental here, the solution will need to be in c# / .net

Comment: That's not valid JSON: please include valid JSON, and information on how you are parsing it.

Comment: hi richard, I've made an edit to my post for clarity - JSON is not the focal point here, it's the data that I happened to have retrieved from a JSON object!

Comment: The input data structures – whatever its source – are key here. Without knowing what object model you're transforming it is impossible to define the transform (where "transform" is any form of extract/aggregate/search/… operation). Hence the "give us the input format *exactly*" comment.

Comment: we need the real representation of your data to give valid parsing advice

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, it looks like the data is not in a very good structure. My best approach would be:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.Count(); i += 2)
{
    var value = data[i];
    var endTime = data[i + 1];
    // Perform transformation with this
}
```

It's not the prettiest thing I've seen. But it should get you started.